# preventing arithmetic with variables of different units

Tags: c++

We have c++ routines with variables in both imperial and metric units. Because of external data formats it's not practical to convert everything to a single measurement system. Mixing the units in an equation without conversion causes errors that can be difficult to find. I can use typedef to create an imperial or metric data type but that doesn't prevent mixed use. I can add a suffix "I" or "M" to the variable name to make units more obvious but that also doesn't prevent mixed use. Can anyone suggest a way to designate the units a variable uses so the compiler (or static analysis tool) can flag mixed use?

Comment: How about using different types for different units?

Comment: you could have a look at [Units and measures for C++ 11](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088293/Units-and-measures-for-Cplusplus) or [boost.units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)

Comment: The standard solution for this is to use strong typedefs with different type for different units.

Comment: This has got user defined literals written all over it.

Comment: @Bathsheba mind blown, first time I'm [seeing this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) :o

Answer (score 4):

For starters, for such *strong typing*, you can define different type for each unit and then enforce the mixing rules by using templated versions of the different equation. Something along the extendable lines of this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Imperial
{
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct Metric
{
    T value;
};

template <typename U>
void SomeEquation(U lhs, U rhs)
{
    // Equation logic
}

int main()
{
    Imperial<double> feet{3.28084};
    Metric<double> meters{1.0};

    SomeEquation(feet, feet);      // OK
    SomeEquation(meters, meters);  // OK
    //SomeEquation(feet, meters);    // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

You could, if you want, specialize equation code for specific unit type:

```
template <typename T>
void SomeEquation(Metric<T> lhs, Metric<T> rhs)
{
    // Specialized equation logic for metric types
}
```

And thanks to [*user defined literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) -- which were mentioned in the comments for me to just discover :o --  you can (since C++11) modify the code to add such definitions:

```
Imperial<long double> operator"" _foot(long double value)
{
    return Imperial<long double>{value};
}

Metric<long double> operator"" _meter(long double value)
{
    return Metric<long double>{value};
}
```

And then have your usage the following convenient way:

```
int main()
{
    auto feet = 3.28084_foot;
    auto meters = 1.0_meter;

    SomeEquation(feet, feet);      // OK
    SomeEquation(meters, meters);  // OK
    //SomeEquation(feet, meters);    // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

You can play around with it [live here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZnLi3A).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "strong types", i.e. a templated wrapper around a primitive type (`int` or `double` or even a `std::string`) that makes imperial and metric different types. Using different types will make the compiler complain about illegal assignments and operations.

One way of implementing strong types with all the background can be found here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/

You can take that idea further and implement operators for convenient arithmetics.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Exactly the info I was looking for. Much appreciated.